# How to find if a string contains uppercase letters and digits

Tags: python, regex

I want to know if a **string matches certain conditions**. For this case, I want this two conditions:

- It contains at least 2 uppercase English alphabet characters.
- It contains at least 3 digits.

Comment: You forgot to post your code that produces the wrong result.

Comment: Hello, i tried to help you without knowing your code. Check if my answer helps.

Comment: Hello, if my answer is validated, please upvote it :) ill appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This** should help:

```
import re
# Check if the string has 3 digits or more
def haveDigits(text):
  if len(filter(str.isdigit, text))>=3:
    return True
  else:
    return False

# Check if the string has 2 uppercase letters or more
def haveUppercase(text):
  if len([char for char in text if char.isupper()])>=2:
    return True
  else:
    return False

# First condition
print(haveDigits("hola123")) # True
print(haveDigits("hola12")) # False

# Second condition
print(haveUppercase("hHola")) # False
print(haveUppercase("HHHola")) # True

# Both conditions at the same time
def bothConditions(text):
  if (haveUppercase(text) & haveDigits(text)):
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(bothConditions("HHHola123")) # True
print(bothConditions("hola1")) # False
```

Comment: `if x: return True` `else: return False` is a very roundabout way to spell `return x`

Answer (score 0):

Create two counter variables, one for uppercase letters and one for digits.

Examine each character in the string.  A `for` loop might work well here.

If the character is an uppercase letter, increment the uppercase latter counter.  Otherwise if the letter is a digit, increment the digit counter.

When the loop is finished, if the uppercase letter counter is at least 2 and the digit counter is at least 3, then the string does meet the stated conditions, otherwise it does not.